# Improving performance of a Theano for loop

Tags: for-loop, theano, pymc3

I have the following code that accomplishes what I want to do. But I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing it by avoiding For Loops. Performance is important here since I call these operations many times.

I think it could be improved by using "scan" and "function" but I'm not experienced enough with Theano for it to be obvious to me. I did try putting everything inside a theano.function but it didn't work.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as t
import numpy as np

m=9
n=9
dim=4
W=np.random.random((m,dim))
Y=np.random.random((n,dim))
I=np.random.randint(0,2,(n,m))
I=I.astype(int)

U=theano.shared(np.zeros((n,dim)))

for i in range(n):
    Ui=np.zeros(dim)
    for k in range(m):
        Ui+=t.dot(I[i,k],W[k,:])
    U=t.set_subtensor(U[i,:],Ui/I[i,:].sum())

U+=Y
```

By the way, this is an implementation of the constrained Probabilistic Matrix Factorization (equation 7 in the paper by Salakhutdinov and Mnih). I'm doing it with pymc3 so "W" and "Y" are really stochastic pymc3 tensors (which I believe are just theano tensors).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand how to vectorise your code. For example:

```
Ui=np.zeros(dim)
for k in range(m):
    Ui+=t.dot(I[i,k],W[k,:])
```

can be implemented as:

```
Ui = I[None, i] * W
```

Learn on numpy broadcasting. This is a really powerful way of thinking and it do computation faster and with less memory. This work for NumPy and Theano code. http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/numpy.html#broadcasting

This can be done at other place I think to speed it up even more.